# Redux: How to update one value upon another changing?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

My React Native app deals with 5 data entities. When the app starts, I show a loading screen and send HTTP requests to the REST backend, one for each entity. When responses for all of them are received and data loading is complete, I navigate from the loading screen to the actual app.

I have created a `Download` slice in the redux RTK store with `isLoadingEntity01` ... `isLoadingEntity05` flags with initial `null` values; I set them to `true` before triggering the HTTP request and set them to `false` upon receiving a response.

NOTE: I am aware that this is a rather primitive approach; I am also aware of [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) (which I am not using yet, that's for another day); the points above merely serve to illustrate the context.

The HTTP responses are obviously received in arbitrary order. The setting of some `loadingIsComplete` flag still is trivial: Whenever a response is received and one of the `isLoadingEntity` is set, check them all five and if they're all `true`, set `loadingIsComplete`.

**The question is: Where / how to do this ?**

My first idea was to implement this in every reducer function (and, in order to prevent code duplication, encapsulate it in a separate function). But [reducer functions should be pure](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions) and setting `loadingIsComplete` to me clearly qualifies as side effect - especially considering the arbitrary order in which responses are received.

My second idea was to create a middleware (which I've just been using successfully for other purposes, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129117)). I think this could work, but IMO my problem should be rather common - I have come across this question myself a number of times now, sometimes within the same slice, sometimes across multiple slices across the store - and I'm getting a nagging feeling I'm missing out on some major redux concept.

I have looked into [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), added by RTK as [one of the default middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#included-default-middleware) (which gives me the impression everybody's using this, so I should, too); "thunks are the basic recommended side effects middleware for Redux" sounds to me like this is my answer - but the docs seem mostly concerned with async logic - and there is nothing async in the case I've depicted above, it's just a second update to some value upon a prior update to another.

Would `redux-thunk` still be the appropriate tool for this kind of purpose ?

**My question** What is the canonical Redux / RTK approach to setting one value upon another changing ?

PS: Obviously did my research before asking here, but most SO questions and blog posts in that direction seem to revolve around forms.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "setting one value upon another changing", as generally in React the answer to that is, "don't". Other than that it sounds like you just need 5 action creators which each reduce into the store on success. Your app would be awaiting all 5 datasets to be populated before rendering something other than your wait screen

Answer (score 1):

### Be clean and simple

I didn't get why you have 5 "isLoadingEntity".

but you can write something like

```
const loadingIsComplete = isLoadingEntity01 && isLoadingEntity02 && ...
```

wrap it with useMemo and render your app if "loadingIsComplete" `True` else keep the loader.

> where do you call the HTTP requests? can we see some code?

in short redux-thunk just unify all your reducers, so you will have one store.
for the redux-thunk you can see my open source project:

(https://github.com/omergal99/hello-corona/blob/master/src/store/AppStore.js)

> about update one value in store - I didn't really get your question

but I can tell you that you can update any store wherever you want in your app, you can write to update reducerX after reducerY updated.. it depends your data structure.

Hope I help you as I can, You are welcome to add code or sharpen your question :)